# What connector is this on the Eachine E160 flight control board?

Tags: identification, connector, cable-assemblies

I'm trying to find the exact type of this 3-pin clippy connector - I need another one to connect the SBUS signal to the board:

[image: Connector]

**Measures:**

- Pitch: ~1mm
- Total width: ~6mm
- Total height: ~3mm

I've been browsing the JST website and [some](http://www.jst.com/home21.html) types are close but not an exact match IMHO.

Comment: When dealing with small connectors, accurate measurements are necessary. I usually sketch them and add dimensions from a caliper. There are literally tens of *thousands* of connectors.

Comment: Look for a manufacturers logo on both parts, might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search on Digikey gives a lot of [results](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/rectangular-connectors-housings/319?s=N4IgjCBcoBw1oDGUBmBDANgZwKYBoQB7KAbXADYBOAJkoFYQBdAgBwBcoQBlNgJwEsAdgHMQAXwIxKCEMkjps%2BIqRDlqYaQXIAGAMwQCAdm3VqILTAAs8LYbqWmrDpG58hoieEpSZchbgJiSDJtRxB2Th4BEXExMSA).

[This one](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/molex/5013300300/1531500) looks quite similar to yours.